# Field not displaying correctly on iOS browsers

Tags: html, css, webkit

I am working on a html webpage that has a form. I use css to edit the input fields and they display nicely on desktops and laptops.

[image: Desktop Input]

But when I visited the site on my iOS in both Chrome and Safari the input looked like this

[image: iOS Input]

The CSS I am using is

```
input{
border: 0;
outline: 0;
background: transparent;
border-bottom: 1.5px solid black;
}
```

What am I doing wrong to make it display differently?

Comment: Have you tried `border-radius: 0`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```css
input[type="text"] {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" autofocus>
```

Looks good on mobile, too. (Android)
[image]